# How do I Organize Shared Units in modern Delphi?

Tags: delphi

For over a decade, I have been stuck (lovingly) on Delphi 6 and have developed hundred of thousands of lines of code in a logical (to me) unit structure, where a project tends to be a few hundred lines of code referencing high-level work routines in my "library".  In trying to migrate to XE5, I just can't find a way to have all my library units compiled in one place on the search path, and then just used by the project (and recompiled if necessary), but that the dcus are off with the library source rather than in with each individual project.

I'm just starting to accept that "hello world" takes 2.5Mb in XE5, and I can't stand the idea that each library unit has to be separately compiled into dcus at the project level.  In the "old" days, these unit dcus would sit next to the pas files and not be recompiled if nothing changed in the source file.

The obvious place to look is the Project options, but I can't find the right setting to make the project stop keeping copies of each dcu.

I am vaguely aware that multi-platform development will cause restructuring, but I can't help feeling that there is some compromise position.

There must be something big I am missing.

Comment: So are you looking for how to save your DCU files in a certain place? At least that's what I understand from the question.

Comment: I guess the thing you are missing is called "package". Group your loose "libraries" into packages.

Comment: You can't stand the idea - why?

Comment: You can still use your old way today. Nothing has changed that stops you doing that. If you want to do it, just do it. I would not do that though. How do you handle versioning? How do you handle branching? How does all this fit with your revision control system?

Comment: @JensG - I know gigabytes are cheap, but hundreds of copies of many dozens of unit dcus is absurd.  It makes the simplest test project a 25-50Mb operation.  I'm sorry, but I grew up with measuring things in bytes.  :-}  H.

Comment: This is what Packages were designed to solve :-)

Comment: I have never cared much about DCUs. They are just an intermediate thing that for the most time I don't even want to see. I focus more on the sources, and on the end result. Especially, I personally don't like the DCUs in the same folder amongst the sources, thus I always configured the DCU output folder to something sane since that option exists. If you value disk space that highly, you could add a post-build step which deletes all the DCUs (and in fact, that's exactly what happens on our CI servers -  they always perform a clean build). Or consider using a RAM disk to hold all the DCUs.

Comment: @JensG With today's technology, it's hard to believe DCU disk usage could be of any problem, and resorting to a RAM disk for something like this seems very excessive.

Comment: I can only guess about the OP's priorities. There are a lot of funky people out there.

Comment: @JensG - it is not the bytes of space I most object to, it is the clutter of thousands or tens of thousands of unimportant files obscuring the actual important stuff.  I understand the theoretical basis for the compilation structure for multiple platforms, but I've developed years of habits and ways of thinking that can't be trivially discarded.  I will change if I have to, but not unless there are important (to me) results.  For example, wide strings have zero importance to me, but the change broke many perfectly good routines for someone else's benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Delphi XE2, Delphi supports compilation for multiple platforms, as well as different build configurations. Because of this, Delphi needs to create DCU files for each combination. For example, `Win32`, `Win64`, and `OS-X` DCU files are saved in separate folders by default. Otherwise, if it weren't like this, the DCU files would overwrite each other, which you should avoid (if you use different configurations/platforms).

These settings can be changed in the Project Options  in the very first section `Delphi Compiler` by modifying the `Unit output directory`. This is by default `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)` which creates a subfolder for the platform, then another subfolder for the config, for example `\Win32\Debug\`. Careful for the `Target` at the very top, which by default is set to your current platform/config. You would typically want to first change it to `All Configurations`. If you clear this field completely from the options, it will produce your default behavior from older versions.

It sounds like you should create a [Package](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Packages). This would allow you to group all your "library" units together in one place (BPL). This package can then be installed into your IDE, and if you have any components, those components can then be installed into your component pallet.

Or you can do without a package too. All the units from all these different projects should be moved to this central place though - a single folder containing all your "library" units. This way it's less maintenance, and you can just add that one folder to your global library path.

If you put your files in a central folder, and use those files from a project, the DCU files for both the project and this "library" will be saved for that project. Delphi doesn't know that these files are a "library", it just knows that you're using them, and since it can't find an already compiled version of those units, it creates one in your project. If you want the DCU files to be saved only once and in this central place, then you would need a package.

Comment: OK - "package" I can relate to, never wrote one, but when I dig out my old Delphi books, they go on about design time and run time and relate them to DLLs.  I don't want something that is distributed separately from the EXE, and, initially, I don't want to add components - just bundle 15-20 units that only reference the basic "SysUtils, Classes, Types, DateUtils, Graphics" plus each other.  My expectation would be that this would all get explicitly compiled to something (bpl?) then get placed on a project's search path.  Am I in the right ballpark?

Comment: Creating a package as I mentioned is optional. You can go without one, but it seems like all you want to do is put all these units together in one folder and use them from different projects. A BPL is the project output of a package.

Comment: I don't want to do something that will keep me from eventually building for multiple platforms.  Yesterday, I tried to modify the "unit output directory" for the project, but the results didn't make sense to me - the "build" kept rebuilding all referenced units to the project debug folder, and, I do want the unit1.dcu to stay local to the project.

Comment: If you put your files in a central folder, and use those files from a project, the DCU files for both the project and this "library" will be saved for that project. Delphi doesn't know that these files are a "library", it just knows that you're using them, and since it can't find an already compiled version of those units, it creates one in your project. If you want the DCU files to be saved only once and in this central place, then you would need a package.

Comment: In a related question - Is there some sort of very high level documentation for Delphi that discusses projects, units, and such.  Again, back in the last century, Delphi came with a "guide" as well as a reference manual.  The docwiki semms to be totally a reference structure.

Comment: OK - a package.  I ought to be able to track that down.  Thanks - Howard

Comment: I do not think what package is good idea. It is a DLL after all. @HNRSoftware, did you consider adopting directory scheme uses by Delphi?

Comment: @FreeConsulting It still solves the issue OP has and OP might take advantage of it and make some components for the IDE :-)

Comment: Guys a package is NOT a dll. It CAN be compiled as BPL, but it can also be compiled as dcu's and linked into a single exe.

Comment: @Free Consulting - not sure what you mean. I think you are talking about ...source... and ...lib...  I think you have something there, but I don't see how to structure it.  It "feels" like I need a project that puts my library dcus in a specific place, and then put that "place" in all my project search paths (or the library path).  Is this where you are going?

Comment: Can one of you put this in the form of an answer?  Too much shorthand here.  Assume a collection of 25 unit pas files in a folder "HNRLIB4".  Where do I put the folder, how do I compile the units and where do I place the DCUs for use by projects?  Thanks

Comment: That would still cause the same behavior of compiling a different DCU per project, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @HNRSoftware, yes, just as `$(DELPHI)\Lib` organized. Place your sources in some directory (add to browsing path), build them for every supported platform and configuration combination, placing dcus to corresponding directory and adding that directory to library path.

Comment: @Free Consulting -- With a little trial and error, I got that trick to work.  I THINK this is doing what I want, but I am still really early in the migration process - still doing string to AnsiString conversions - my code is THAT old.  I just have a dummy project whose only real function is to compile the units, and then I added that dcu path to my library path.  When I recompile one of the other projects, it grabs those dcus and just places the Unit1.dcu in its own win32\debug folder.  Fingers crossed, but I think this works.

Comment: @HNRSoftware Why are you trying to use `AnsiString`? If you want to use `AnsiString`, stick to D6.

Comment: @David Heffernan -- Many reasons.  First, I have 20 years of Delphi projects that I need to keep working.  For the forseeable future, that will be making minimum changes to working code to be compatible with D6 and XE5.  Reason for XE5 - MANY capability improvements especially internet-related.  REST is specific need - never got an OAuth to work right in D6.  As much as I love D6, I need to move forward and make the pain as little as possible.

Comment: If you want to reduce pain, stop using ansistring

Comment: This is a silly argument.  Wide strings and UTFs of all flavors are fine for many things - JUST NOT EVERYTHING.  There were neat things you could do with the old Delphi 1 strings with the length byte at the beginning, but AnsiStrings were a wonderful improvement. I will be happy to avoid AnsiStrings in the future, but it is not fair to redefine a string as something that is incompatible with perfectly fine existing code to give me the ability to include Chinese ideograms in my apps.  It is not trivial to upgrade my code to use new features when I can't get by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me thank all the respondents to this question - all provided useful insight.  I experimented with the various suggestions (including breaking XE5 so badly that I had to reinstall -- at least I learned some areas not to mess with.)

1. Important to me, but a known bad coding practice, is having individual projects edit shared library units (only my own units - I do not mess with code belonging to Delphi or 3-rd party).  This is critical to having multiple applications working on the same data, but in bite-sized pieces.  the shared code lets me make high-level pieces of an app available to other projects.  There might be better ways (I would love to hear about them), but this has worked for me for a long time.
2. The multi-platform model really requires the dcu structure used by default, so I will adapt to it.  Share the source code, but accept multiple compilations to individual projects. A good suggestion by JensG is just to clean up the dcus when the project is not actively being worked on.  Should be straight-forward utility program.
3. The D6 -> XE5 migration (which will take months for some of the less used areas) requires me to know which units compile successfully, so I will maintain one project whose function is to include all units and recompile them all.  This will make it practical to map library unit pas files to dcu files.
4. The AnsiString/AnsiChar <-> String/Char problem is the major migration problem area.  Simply making edit-level changes may get the code past the compiler, but there is no guarantee that the code still works the same way.  Especially troubling is at interface points to Windows calls and such.  My answer will be to make the units compilable first, but then write test code for trouble areas.  This is what will take the months - I need to get on with new stuff, as well as fixing the old.  I REALLY don't know yet if I will be able to substitute the XE5 compatible code back into Delphi 6 without another layer of testing.  I THINK it should work, but it will take careful checking.
5. A second major migration problem is 3rd party code such as VCLZip.  XE5 has its own zip support, but I have a lot of places where I use VCLzip and the conversion will not be trivial.  For this specific library, it may be possible to find XE5-level source and simply work it in.  There are other pieces of code gotten from the internet that I used, but never needed to truly understand which will cause significant hassles.

Again - thank you to all.  This has been an interesting 24 hours.  Howard